# Override Bettercms Module Controller with custom Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bettercms

BetterCMS has its own `XML Sitemap` generator as seen here: 
[GoogleSitemapController](https://github.com/devbridge/BetterCMS/blob/dev/Modules/BetterCms.Module.GoogleAnalytics/Controllers/GoogleSitemapController.cs)
I've recreated this controller with a few amends to include pages that aren't currently located in the sitemap, which generates the `XML` for the sitemap but my version isn't executing. As this GoogleSitemapController usually creates the /sitemap.xml when the project is running, my version of the GoogleSitemapController is not being caught by my breakpoints.

From my own knowledge I believe the best way is to include the reference for the controller in the `App_Start/RouteConfig` where I should create a `MapRoute`. However My version of the controller doesnt work is there anything I could be possibly missing.

Comment: You "basically" recreated it? So what did you do different? Show us what you've done. And it's not rendering? What does that mean? You need to add lots more relevant information here before anyone can help.

Comment: So the original is set up primarily focusing on the nodes within the sitemap. However, in my work I have pages that are dynamically created that wouldn't be classed as a node. So the small addition is to include these pages within the Sitemap.xml

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'll correct my post